# Showing dynamically elements from a thread in java/android

Tags: java, android, view

I'm debuting with Java developpment on Android, and I'm encountering a difficulty.

I want to fetch some elements from a database and then display them.

My app is composed of :
MainActivity, which displays MainFragment. On MainActivity there is a button changing MainFragment to SecondFragment, or SecondFragment to MainFragment.

DataBaseAccess class which I use to load and interact with a room database. In order to do so, I can't use the Main Thread so I use a Thread  to run the code that loads and gets info from the database.
Here is my onCreateView in MainFragment :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
 
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
              String data_fetched = "";
            // Here there is code to load the database and put the data I want in data_fetched
          
            ((Activity)getContext()).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    LinearLayout l = ((Activity) getContext()).findViewById(R.id.main_main_space);

                    TextView text = new TextView(getContext());

                    text.setText("Fetched info : " +data_fetched);
                    l.addView(text);

                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
    return v;
```

My problem is that the code works on the first time I load MainFragment, but when I load SecondFragment and reload MainFragment,  the text that I want to display doesn't print.
Maybe my approach isn't correct, as I've said I'm new to android developpment so if there are better practices please correct me !

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was in the way I changed between fragments.

```
public void onClick(View v){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.fr_layout, TreatmentsFragment.class, null)
                    .commit();
        }
```

is what I used, and

```
public void onClick(View v){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .replace(R.id.fr_layout, TreatmentsFragment.class, null)
                    .commit();
        }
```

is what resolved my issue.